# Piece of code to execute AFTER execution of other code

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a piece of code I want to execute after another piece of code. Now I'm using setTimeout but it's not a good solution.

For example, I'm using a text editor which of course needs time for initialization.

```
myTextEditor.initialize();
setHeightToMyTextEditor();
```

In this example, the height to myTextEditor isn't right. It stays the same, because the text editor still isn't initialized. So, I'm using setTimeout and execute setHeightToMyTextEditor() after 3 seconds. But, if someone has much slower internet I guess it will be a problem.

So, how to make setHeightToMyTextEditor() execute after the text editor is initialized?

Comment: What asynchronous code does `.initialize` do?

Comment: You need to be more specific regarding the `initialize` method

Comment: It's from external .js files.

Comment: Even if I do agree that using setTimeout is not the best solution I want to point out that "internet speed" isn't an issue at all since the javascript file is downloaded as a whole and then executed.

Answer (score 0):

So you have to wirte it in callback function of intialize.

please refer the jquery callback tutorial .

```
http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.Callbacks/
```

example :

```
    $(document).ready(function(){
  $("button").click(function(){
    $("p").hide("slow",function(){
      alert("The paragraph is now hidden");
    });
  });
});
```